# For what values of $k$, $t_{0}$, or $x$ is this integral convergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

$$I(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}{({-\xi})^{1.5k}\sin{(\xi{t_{0})}}e^{-i\xi{x}}}d\xi,$$
$k$ is an integer greater or equal to $0$, $t_{0}\in[0,\infty)$, $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$.
I need to find an approximate evaluation of the integral using quadratures, so I need to be sure of convergence.

Comment: Your integral is an oscillatory integral so you must check that function you put into it is either $L^1$ or $L^2$.
You can try to use the Euler formula for $sin$ and obtain two integral of the form an complex eponential times a power function.